# Vertx: passing additional variable between verticles

Tags: java, rx-java, vert.x

I have a service which mostly proxies another server adding some business logic to its responses. So it just receives a requests, sends similar request to another server(should be sent with specific user cookie which comes with request), applies some changes to response, and sends it back to user.

I am using vertx with rx-java, and currently I have two verticles.

One of them accepts rest requests and as a part of processing this requests calls a method on another verticle via `evenBus`:

```
 router.route().handler(routingContext -> {
     someService.handleRequest()
                .subscribe(res -> ...send response...);
 }
```

And somewhere in `handleRequest` there is a call to another verticle:

```
     eventBus.rxSend(address, message, deliveryOptions);
```

Another verticle listens to this address and send request to another server:

```
 eventBus.consumer(address)
         .toObservable()
         .subscribe(message -> {
             response = anotherService.handleMessage(message);
             message.reply(response.body());
         });
```

And somewhere in `handleMessage` it calls vertx `httpclient` making a request to another server:

```
response = client.get(...);
```

This request should contain cookie value from initial request received in first verticle with routing context.

What is the right way to pass the cookie value from `routingContext` to vertx `httpclient` in another verticle? (I don't want to change interfaces by adding new method parameter everywhere, it should be handled implicitly)

As far as I understand the best way to pass some additional value between verticles is using `headers` in `DeliveryOptions`.
But what is the right and safe way to store it between service calls(e.g. pass it to `handleRequest`/`handleMessage` without modyfing method signature)?(possibly storing it in verticle context?)

Comment: You can put some data in the verticle context, but beware it will be visible to any event (not just your method call). But I would simply change the method signature and pass along a `CallContext` object. Then in the future you can add more data without breaking your API. Vert.x 4 will have asynchronous context support.

Comment: @Ruslan when you say secure do you mean that you don't trust the event bus pipe to man in the middle? Or do you have something else in mind.

You could `encrypt -> event-pipe->decrypt->client` i.e. do encryption by yourself.

Also why do you want to pass cookie as an header, why not as part of your message?

Comment: @MangatRaiModi no, sorry, I said "safe" meaning that it will work properly. I am relatively new to vertx, for example one of the ways of doing that I mentioned was putting cookie into context, the problem is that I am not sure that some other execution will not see it. e.g. there two sequentiall calls to verticle via event bus, handling the first call I have updated context with cookie value, can it be that execution of second call will be on the same context before first finishes its execution?

Comment: @tsegismont I am not sure about if that context approach is safe to use. Can you pelase clarify one this: Presume there are two almost simulteneous calls to same verticle via eventbus, is it possible that the second call execution will sart on the same vertx context before first is finished?

Comment: @RuslanAkhundov I believe you mean vert.x context. Every vertical in same vertx instance share the context. But Vert.x concurrency model makes sure that the access to context is thread safe.

Note that, if you use eventbus, you should program in a way that both the verticals are independent and  messages on eventbus is the only way to share data. Keep them in silos. Don't rely on vert.x context at all.

Comment: Best way is what you mentioned in the question. In vertical-1, get the cookies, and pass them over event-bus either as part of message or header. In vertical-2 retrieve and provide cookie to client. Here the verticals are totally independent of the context and message queue is the only way of passing data.

Also ask here:- https://gitter.im/eclipse-vertx/vertx-users